# Как подружить PyDrive и VK Callback API?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, google-drive

Есть простой код бота на Pythonanywere. Это веб приложение на flask. И мне также нужно подключится к моему гугл диску через PyDrive.

```py
from flask import Flask, request, json

import vk_api
import random
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LoadCredentialsFile("mycreds.txt")
if gauth.credentials is None:
    gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
elif gauth.access_token_expired:
    gauth.Refresh()
else:
    gauth.Authorize()
gauth.SaveCredentialsFile("mycreds.txt")
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

vk = vk_api.VkApi(token="токен бота")

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ["POST"])
def main():
    data = json.loads(request.data)
    if data["type"] == "confirmation":
        return "код подтверждения"
    elif data["type"] == "message_new":
        object = data["object"]
        id = object["peer_id"]
        body = object["text"]
        if body.lower() == "привет":
            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "Привет!", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
        elif body.lower() == "тест":
            file1 = drive.CreateFile({'parents': [{'id': "папка"}]})
            file_list = drive.ListFile({'q': "'{}' in parents and trashed=false".format("папка")}).GetList()
            for file1 in file_list:
                if file1['title'] == "a1.jpg":
                    file1.GetContentFile("a1.jpg")
            vk.method("messages.send", {"peer_id": id, "message": "тест", "random_id": random.randint(1, 2147483647)})
    return "ok"
```

Но сервер возвращает ошибку, хотя файл для аутентификации в папке есть (отдельно, ибо pythonanywere не открывает окно авторизации). Что я делаю не так?

```
Error running WSGI application
2020-05-11 20:07:44,355: pydrive.auth.AuthenticationError: No valid credentials provided to authorize
2020-05-11 20:07:44,355:   File "/var/www/redtardis_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2020-05-11 20:07:44,355:     from flask_app import app as application  # noqa
2020-05-11 20:07:44,355: 
2020-05-11 20:07:44,356:   File "/home/RedTardis/mysite/flask_app.py", line 10, in <module>
2020-05-11 20:07:44,356:     gauth.Authorize()
2020-05-11 20:07:44,356: 
2020-05-11 20:07:44,356:   File "/home/RedTardis/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pydrive/auth.py", line 521, in Authorize
2020-05-11 20:07:44,356:     raise AuthenticationError('No valid credentials provided to authorize')
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что `mycreds.txt` лежит в **рабочей папке** приложения? Попробуйте указать абсолютный путь.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов мне удалось решить проблему, оказалось банальная ошибка со стороны pythonanywere, нужно было обновить модули. Подключится удалось, но как это обычно бывает, другая ошибка - `file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0 or google-auth`. Нужно отключить кэш, но я не совсем понимаю как

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашёл решение этой ошибки на форуме [pythonanywere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/27344/)
Оказалось, это ошибка со стороны сервера, всё что нужно было сделать - обновить PySocks в bash консоли:

`pip3.8 install --user --force-reinstall PySocks`